# Passenger enterprise standalone rolling restarts slow first request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Whenever my Passenger enterprise standalone does a rolling restart, a delay of ~6 seconds occurs for the first request(s) to the new instance of the application. Any ideas why this is the case? My guess is that it has something to do with the swapping of the socket file.

Note: This is a Rails 3 application and I can see in the logs that the application is preloading and requests still go through quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of the swapping of the socket. Passenger Enterprise already takes care of that for you ensures that that particular aspect is fast. Most likely, your app requires some additional initialization, which isn't done until the first request. I don't know what initialization that is, but if you know then you should move that code to config/application.rb so that initialization occurs before the first request, so that Passenger Enterprise's rolling restarter can correctly take that into account.

Hongli Lai

Phusion CTO

Comment: I believe I may have found it. The previous maintainer set config.assets.precompile to true. Thanks for the clarification.